Alternative Title not showing in Module Drupal 10


<?php

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function alternative_title_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Check if the current route contains a node.
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    // Check if the node type is 'info'.
    if ($node->getType() == 'info') {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Node type is Info');

      
      $node_title = $node->getTitle();
      // Get the alternative title field value.
      $alternative_title = $node->get('field_titel')->value;

      // If an alternative title exists, use it.
      if (!empty($alternative_title)) {
      $variables['#title'] = $alternative_title;
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($variables['#title']);
      } 
    } else {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Node type is not Info, node type is "' . $node->getType() . '"');
    }
  }
}



My goal is to write a module which shows an alternative title instead of the real title if the alternative title is not empty. Somehow the $variables['#title'] gets the change of the title in the Messenger but on the actual page it's still showing the old title.
Maybe I have to change the title in a different way, but I am not sure how.
Thanks for the help!

check your twig file and replace the title value with your alternative title

Are you getting the correct field? Check if "$node->get('field_titel')->value;" is not meant to be "$node->get('field_title')->value;"
